# TFS 2013 Installation Error: TF400167

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to install TFS 2013 i am getting the below error

"Error : TF400167 : Installation failed for the package(tfs_sharePointExtensionsCore_x64) with the following status 0x80070652, restart state 00x0."

I have also tried clearing "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache", but still throws the same error.

Kindly help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Thanks
prashanth

Answer (score 1):

Could you be low on free disk space?

Comment: This was my problem - old post but helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing down all files and folders within C:\ProgramData\Package Cache worked for me, while installing onto Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the antivirus or turn off it. That could be the reason. That worked for me.